# Flipping keyframes in walk cycle animation not working

Tags: animation, rigging

I try to flip my keyframes like in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/7o6sUxwMEnU?t=28s).

I do everything exactly like in the video, but it fails.

[image]

[image]

1. Select all bones from armature.
2. Set timeline frame to 80
3. Select all keyframes from frame 1
4. Click on [image: copy symbol in dope sheet - action editor]
5. Click on [image: paste symbol in dope sheet - action editor]

[image]

**Result:**

[image: result (very weird bone positions)]

What am I doing wrong? I just try to flip the keyframes like in the video.
The bones are named with the naming convention `name.L` and `name.R`.

I was already reading many same questions, but there is no working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something weird is going on, but you can solve it by selecting in edit mode all the .L bones, delete them, then select all the .R bones, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, <kbd>Esc</kbd> not to move them, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> set the cursor to center, make the cursor pivot point, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>  <kbd>X</kbd> to mirror the bones on the X axis, Then Armature - Flip Names.

Everything now works as expected.

The reverse (L-R) of this whole operation doesn't work!

Comment: If I do this then all my inverse kinematic setup and weight painting gets lost

Comment: No, everything remains, as the "flip names" functions is intelligent and the mirror copies constraints also. Try it on a copy file. The only thing that you'll have to redo is the animation (the single pose, in fact) as the "weird" thing affects it also.

Comment: But I just tried it with the exact steps from you and the inverse kinematic is lost :/

Comment: Try inverting L and R

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, this is an animation problem, not a rigging problem.

It looks like the rollMain.R bone has rotation data only in the x channel (the y and z channels have been cleared), but rollMain.L has keys in all three (x, y, and z rotation channels). When a situation like this comes up, the x rotation data is copied into all three channels on the 'mirror to' bone. The fix is to do this:
- Clear Single Keyframes on the y and z rotation channels for rollMain.L
- make sure auto key is turned off
- set the y and z rotation channels to '0'

This problem always comes up when copying single-channel data to a bone where all three channels have keys already set (four channels in the case of quaternion rotation). Blender gets confused and puts the single channel data into all channels.